# "Many of them [adjective]" vs "many of which are [adjective]"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I encountered this sentence in a book:

"Scattered across the North American continent were about 500 different groups, **many of them nomadic**."

Should the last clause be replaced with "**many of which were nomadic**"? I could find nothing with a quick Google search.

Comment: You could, but it's not essential. _Many of them nomadic_ is a verbless clause. Verbless clauses like this have a subject and predicate structure and function as an adjunct. The predicational relationship is like that expressed in _many of them were nomadic_. The adjunct is comparable to the supplementary relative clause _many of which were nomadic_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rephrase the sentence, it will become:

> About 500 different groups **were** scattered across the North American
>   continent **and** many of them **were** nomadic.

There are two clauses in the above sentence, first of which is inverted. Do we really need the second **were** in the sentence to mean what it is supposed to mean? The answer is "No."

The first sentence is inverted (probably) for emphasis. The "and" is replaced by the "comma" and "are" is not required at all. As @BillJ commented, it's not essential.

You need to note that you can't omit "were" if you want to use "many of which" in place of "many of them".

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! We're looking for .... eh, hello there!

Comment: I believe that you may be oversimplifying this.  I can say, “I ate 366 apples last year, many of them rotten.”  The “many of them [adjective]” construct works even if the sentence doesn’t otherwise contain a form of the verb **to be**.  … … … … … … …  P.S. Welcome back.